# Exchange a version nr

Tags: regex

I have the following line in a web.config file.

```
<add assembly="xxxxx, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=CCCCDDDSWFRWSSFSDS"/>
```

What I want is to find the Version=1.0.0.0 and be able to replace the 1.0.0.0 with my own nr.

How do I find it with regex?

Comment: Come on, how much easier can a regular expression get? Did you put any effort into solving this yourself?

Comment: @user1540911 :  Which language you are using ?

Comment: C#. Well the 1.0.0.0 could be diffrent. So I am not sure... It changes all the time.

Answer (score 1):

The *problem* with what you want to match is that it has periods (`.`), which in regular expression language is a special character. To go round this problem the period character needs to be escaped with a `\`, so you regex should as follows: `Version=1\.0\.0\.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you're using Perl and the line is in variable $_.

```
my $new_nr = "2.3.4.5";
s/(Version=)\S+,/$1$new_nr,/;
```